# How can I stack data correctly using kusto into a columnchart

Tags: azure, kql, azure-monitoring

I have the following kusto query:

```
AACHttpRequest
| where StatusCode != 200
| summarize ErrorCount=count() by bin(TimeGenerated, 1d), StatusCode
```

This gives me data like this:

[image]

Now I want to render this in a stacked columnchart, but if I add the `render columnchart` it does this:
[image]

This is not what I want, I want the graph to stack the errorCount, with different colors and then display the StatusCode in the legend, so you would get something like this (picture taken from internet blog):

[image]

What do I need to to do to get to this result? Any help is very much appreciated.

In case it matters, the data is from Azure Monitor.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You probably need to specify [more properties](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-explorer/kusto/query/visualization-columnchart?pivots=azuredataexplorer) for the column chart for this to look how you want it.

```
let T = datatable(TimeGenerated:datetime, StatusCode:int, ErrorCount:int) [
datetime("2024-03-26"), 304, 3,
datetime("2024-03-26"), 404, 5,
datetime("2024-03-27"), 304, 10,
datetime("2024-03-27"), 404, 2,
datetime("2024-03-27"), 405, 1,
datetime("2024-03-28"), 404, 1,
datetime("2024-03-28"), 301, 2
];
T
| extend StatusCode = tostring(StatusCode)
| render columnchart with (kind=stacked, series=StatusCode)
```

[image]

Edit: Sorry noticed you said Azure Monitor, we need to do something slightly different, see the updated code above for Log Analytics functional.